# Android: Retrive data from database for specific value

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am making an Android app that get the data from URL stores it in to the database (I am done till this stage) and use some of the field of that table.

I tried to fetch the specific data using this SQL query

```
"select persons_name where persons_name=s"
```

but there was an error

> I/Database(23722): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = near "FROM": syntax error

Comment: the obtained value should be distinct as well.

Comment: so, does that mean you can just not use FROM in your statement?

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify in which table the data is located.

The correct SQL is:

```
select persons_name FROM Persons where persons_name=s
```

assuming the table is Persons

Comment: The table name is Persons and it has three fields persons_name, persons_age, row_id.

Comment: then that is your answer, you forgot the FROM clause, which is mandatory

Answer (score 1):

This will be select all names who have name starting letter is 's'

```
"SELECT persons_name FROM persons WHERE persons_name LIKE 's%'
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @JesusS, try this:

```
"SELECT persons_name FROM persons WHERE persons_name LIKE 's'"
```

Comment: You may use it with `db.rawQuery`

Comment: It gives me error when I tried to use this particular query. got this error: 07-24 18:47:54.003: E/AndroidRuntime(3692): FATAL EXCEPTION: main